# How to delete each value separately on array?

Tags: javascript, html

I got 2 different array display value, but the value was delete at the same time when I clicked a button next to the display value.

```
    function deleteItem(i) {
        objectarray.splice(i,1);
        displayList();
    }
```

Comment: You iterating depending on length of `objectarray`. And after removing item, which will reduce the length of `objectarray`, rerending.

Comment: provide complete example.  add html code and css

Comment: @DCR Do you know how to put full code? Sorry I am not famliar this site.

Comment: I've looked at your code.  You have a lot going on and it's a little hard to follow.  You have a lot that needs to be redone.  May I suggest you start with some pseudo code and once you have the design figure out it shouldn't be too hard.  When you think of your project consider 3 sections: 1 section for input, 1 section that manipulates the inputs, 1 section that outputs your results.

Answer (score 0):

The naive solution is to use separate arrays. So you can try to use two objectarrays.

I might be able to help more if you put your code on codepen.io or soomething. Its difficult to follow here.

Comment: The structure of the application is a quite messed up. Cannot address all of them.
The core problem is that you are passing "Del" (this.value [line 207]) into the deleteItem function. 
So there is now way for the deleteItem function to know what to delete. 
You can start by console.loggging what the deleteItem function is receiving and then indentify the item that has to be deleted using various methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issue. Can't be fix all. You can start with modifiying things like:

// Appending pizza order, pass type `pizza` on delete

```
    displayPizza += `<input type="radio" name="listitem" value="${i}" onchange="modifyCusInfo(this.value)"> <input type="button" name="listitem"  value="Del" onclick="deleteItem(this.value, 'pizza')">&nbsp&nbsp${pzInvoice}<br>`;
```

// Appending sand order, pass type `sand` on delete

```
    displaySand += `<input type="radio" name="listitem" value="${x}" onchange="modifyCusInfo(this.value)">&nbsp&nbsp <input type="button" name="listitem" value="Del" onclick="deleteItem(this.value, 'sand')">&nbsp&nbsp${sandInvoice}<br>`;
```

// Modify deleteItem

```
function deleteItem(i, type) {
  let cusorder = objectarray[i];
  if (type === "pizza") {
    cusorder.pzOrderList.pop();
  }
  if (type === "sand") {
    cusorder.sandOrderList.pop();
  }
  displayList();
}
```

Similarly, pass index of the pizza or sandwich, and remove particular from 
`cusorder.sandOrderList` or `cusorder.pzOrderList`

Comment: Popping will work only when there is only one item in the list of the customer wants to delete the last item. 

As the question asks, @JayXD wants the user to select more that one item.

Comment: I know, i have highlighted that in my answer, his code is a little messy to understand. too many global variables. He can modify accordingly. I have given guidance.

Comment: I tried to put your code, but I got this message "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' " . I couldn't find '}' this one, but if I reback my code by remove your It didn't hava an error.

Comment: Sorry but there are many issue. Even html has been not created properly :(